# Problem with texture mapping on my glb model three.js

Tags: vue.js, three.js, 3d

I'm new to this field.
I upload my model and try to add the textures I need to it.
`const textureloader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

```
    const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
      map: textureloader.load('./assets/textures/albedo/albedo-wood.png'),
    });

    var mat;

    loader.load(modelPath, (glb) => {
          
      const mesh = glb.scene;

      glb.scene.traverse( function( object ) {  
        if ((object instanceof THREE.Mesh))
          { 
            if (object.material) {
              mat = object.material;

              object.map = material.map;
              object.map.needsUpdate = true;
            }
          } 
      });

      this.scene.add(glb.scene);
```

`
but for some reason, the texture is displayed incorrectly. The only thing I think is that the problem may be with uv scanning, but I'm new to this topic, so I'm not even sure what it is.

I also noticed that the texture is displayed correctly inside my object.

[image]

[image]

The model itself is correct and so are the textures. I checked on different sites, individually
The model itself is a rounded cube

Answer (score 0):

- The [UV mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping) (flat representation of your 3D model) is not right.
- To check it in a render, you can use a UV checker that is a texture with recognizable symbols  (you can generate it from [uvchecker.vinzi](https://uvchecker.vinzi.xyz/)).
- The most easiest approach here would be to edit the UV of your model from a modeling software (like Blender), and check how to "unwrap UV" correctly. There is two approach for cubes, [each face have the same UV](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=cube#webgl_geometry_cube) or you have [the "dicey" unwrap](https://people.engr.tamu.edu/sueda/courses/CSC471/2016S/demos/khongton/images/cubemaps_skybox.jpg).